# Typo in my textbook about integrals?

Tags: definite-integrals

I am reading about integrals:

[image]

The right hand side of the last equation reads:

$$ ... x^3 \cdot 1 \cdot x \cdot \sin x... $$

Is that $1$ supposed to be a $+$ instead?

Comment: You're right, it must be $x^3+x\sin x$.

Comment: Yes.$\phantom{}$

Comment: Yes, Please let the publisher know.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention which textbook this is, so that if anyone searches for typos of that textbook then this post can show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters confirmed, that is indeed a typo, and letting the publisher know would be a good idea, so that future students aren't confused as well.

As a quick sanity check, $x^3+x\sin x$ does make much more sense in that context than $x^4\sin x$ would.